# Thread 2: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Tags: swift, xcode, multithreading

I am new to coding. Currently, working on changing the bundle identifier name of existing application. Code was running "Thread 2: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)" at the end. Appreciate, if anyone can break this down for me.

```
libsystem_c.dylib`__abort:
0x7fff5219bb8b <+0>:   pushq  %rbp
0x7fff5219bb8c <+1>:   movq   %rsp, %rbp
0x7fff5219bb8f <+4>:   pushq  %r15
0x7fff5219bb91 <+6>:   pushq  %r14
0x7fff5219bb93 <+8>:   pushq  %r12
0x7fff5219bb95 <+10>:  pushq  %rbx
0x7fff5219bb96 <+11>:  subq   $0x20, %rsp
0x7fff5219bb9a <+15>:  cmpq   $0x0, 0x37c0e976(%rip)    ; gCRAnnotations + 7
0x7fff5219bba2 <+23>:  jne    0x7fff5219bbb2            ; <+39>
0x7fff5219bba4 <+25>:  leaq   0x6741(%rip), %rax        ; "__abort() called"
0x7fff5219bbab <+32>:  movq   %rax, 0x37c0e966(%rip)    ; gCRAnnotations + 8
0x7fff5219bbb2 <+39>:  leaq   -0x30(%rbp), %r12
0x7fff5219bbb6 <+43>:  andq   $0x0, -0x8(%r12)
0x7fff5219bbbc <+49>:  movl   $0xffffffff, %eax         ; imm = 0xFFFFFFFF 
0x7fff5219bbc1 <+54>:  movq   %rax, (%r12)
0x7fff5219bbc5 <+58>:  pushq  $0x6
0x7fff5219bbc7 <+60>:  popq   %r15
0x7fff5219bbc9 <+62>:  leaq   -0x38(%rbp), %r14
0x7fff5219bbcd <+66>:  movl   %r15d, %edi
0x7fff5219bbd0 <+69>:  movq   %r14, %rsi
0x7fff5219bbd3 <+72>:  xorl   %edx, %edx
0x7fff5219bbd5 <+74>:  callq  0x7fff521320ac            ; sigaction
0x7fff5219bbda <+79>:  andb   $-0x21, 0x8(%r14)
0x7fff5219bbdf <+84>:  leaq   -0x24(%rbp), %rsi
0x7fff5219bbe3 <+88>:  orl    $-0x1, (%rsi)
0x7fff5219bbe6 <+91>:  pushq  $0x3
0x7fff5219bbe8 <+93>:  popq   %rbx
0x7fff5219bbe9 <+94>:  movl   %ebx, %edi
0x7fff5219bbeb <+96>:  xorl   %edx, %edx
0x7fff5219bbed <+98>:  callq  0x7fff5219c832            ; symbol stub for: sigprocmask
0x7fff5219bbf2 <+103>: pushq  $0x1
0x7fff5219bbf4 <+105>: popq   %rdi
0x7fff5219bbf5 <+106>: callq  0x7fff5219c38e            ; symbol stub for: __pthread_workqueue_setkill
0x7fff5219bbfa <+111>: movl   %ebx, %edi
0x7fff5219bbfc <+113>: movq   %r12, %rsi
0x7fff5219bbff <+116>: xorl   %edx, %edx
0x7fff5219bc01 <+118>: callq  0x7fff5219c7ba            ; symbol stub for: pthread_sigmask
0x7fff5219bc06 <+123>: callq  0x7fff5219c7ae            ; symbol stub for: pthread_self
0x7fff5219bc0b <+128>: movq   %rax, %rdi
0x7fff5219bc0e <+131>: movl   %r15d, %esi
0x7fff5219bc11 <+134>: callq  0x7fff5219c76c            ; symbol stub for: pthread_kill
0x7fff5219bc16 <+139>: movl   $0x2710, %edi             ; imm = 0x2710 
0x7fff5219bc1b <+144>: callq  0x7fff5214d87c            ; usleep$NOCANCEL
0x7fff5219bc20 <+149>: movl   $0xffffffe7, 0x8(%r14)    ; imm = 0xFFFFFFE7 
0x7fff5219bc28 <+157>: movl   %ebx, %edi
0x7fff5219bc2a <+159>: movq   %r12, %rsi
0x7fff5219bc2d <+162>: xorl   %edx, %edx
0x7fff5219bc2f <+164>: callq  0x7fff5219c832            ; symbol stub for: sigprocmask
```

Stack trace:

```
   thread #7, stop reason = EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
  * frame #0: 0x00007fff5219bc34 libsystem_c.dylib`__abort + 169
    frame #1: 0x00007fff5219bb8b libsystem_c.dylib`abort + 135
    frame #2: 0x00007fff500a2858 libc++abi.dylib`abort_message + 231
    frame #3: 0x00007fff50093cbf libc++abi.dylib`demangling_terminate_handler() + 262
    frame #4: 0x00007fff51253c0b libobjc.A.dylib`_objc_terminate() + 96
    frame #5: 0x00007fff500a1c87 libc++abi.dylib`std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 8
    frame #6: 0x00007fff500a440b libc++abi.dylib`__cxxabiv1::failed_throw(__cxxabiv1::__cxa_exception*) + 27
    frame #7: 0x00007fff500a43d2 libc++abi.dylib`__cxa_throw + 113
    frame #8: 0x00007fff51253ad6 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_throw + 340
    frame #9: 0x00007fff25ac3079 Foundation`_AssertAutolayoutOnAllowedThreadsOnly + 428
    frame #10: 0x00007fff25ac2c67 Foundation`-[NSISEngine _optimizeWithoutRebuilding] + 54
    frame #11: 0x00007fff25ac2b9a Foundation`-[NSISEngine optimize] + 100
    frame #12: 0x00007fff25abd8bc Foundation`-[NSISEngine performPendingChangeNotifications] + 82
    frame #13: 0x00007fff4982da80 UIKitCore`-[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 3642
    frame #14: 0x00007fff2b4e9260 QuartzCore`-[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 255
    frame #15: 0x00007fff2b4ef3eb QuartzCore`CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 523
    frame #16: 0x00007fff2b4faa8a QuartzCore`CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 80
    frame #17: 0x00007fff2b443a7c QuartzCore`CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*, double) + 324
    frame #18: 0x00007fff2b477467 QuartzCore`CA::Transaction::commit() + 649
    frame #19: 0x00007fff2b478362 QuartzCore`CA::Transaction::release_thread(void*) + 210
    frame #20: 0x00007fff522b5054 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_tsd_cleanup + 551
    frame #21: 0x00007fff522b7512 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_exit + 70
    frame #22: 0x00007fff522b4ddd libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_wqthread_exit + 77
    frame #23: 0x00007fff522b3afc libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_wqthread + 481
    frame #24: 0x00007fff522b2b77 libsystem_pthread.dylib`start_wqthread + 15
```

Comment: Type "bt" -- no quotes -- at the (lldb) prompt in the debug console when it crashes.  Add the stack trace to your question and it might give some hints.

Comment: I hope the edits would help. Thank you very much

Comment: Yes, the main clue is `_AssertAutolayoutOnAllowedThreadsOnly` along with the fact that it showed your crash happening on thread 7.  That suggests you're doing some work on a background thread and modifying the UI in some way without dispatching to the main thread.